# Can you use 'rand' to generate random operators?

Tags: php, random

Can you use 'rand' to generate random operators?  I have made a php program to add up two random numbers but I want to alter it and make the operator random.  Is using 'rand' the best way.  Thank you

Comment: Random operator? Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424621/how-to-add-random-operator-from-array-in-php ?

Comment: To answer your question directly: no. But there are other ways to do it, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

well you can put operators in an array and then call array_rand to retrive it

```
$ops = array('+','-','*','/');
$rand_key = array_rand($ops);
$operator =- $ops[$rand_key];
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use random and round and switch structor